# creating an http body with construction method

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata, uint32

I am trying to create a http body that I am going to pass in using NSURLRequest post.
I have my connection class all set up.

The thing is i have several methods that return NSStrings and UInt32's and one construction method that I want to use to put all of these methods into one http body which will be of data type format.

However I'm not sure how to call these methods that return the correct data from my construction method to gather the data into one data object.

here is some code that I have (shortened so its a little clearer)

**these methods are used to return the data needed**

```
- (UInt32) addDataVer
{
    UInt32 dataVer = 0;

    return dataVer;

}

- (NSString *) addReg
{
    NSString *reg = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd1"];

    return reg;
}

- (NSString *) addActiv
{
    NSString *activ = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd2"];

    return activ;
}
```

from here I'm not sure what to do, or how to get the data. I have created a construction method, that I want to use to grab the data and then I want to use that data to build a NSData object where I put the returning data into it in order.

this is my construction class

```
- (void) constructRequest
{
  //what the heck do I call in here? lol   
}
```

the last  thing I will have to do is figure out how to put the nsdata representation of each return value into the data object... if that makes sense...

any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE::**

So I figured out how to get the return value into my construction method, by following the force!

```
- (void) constructRequest
{
    NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self addReg]];

    NSLog(@"mystring %@", mystring);
}
```

however I am not sure how to do this with a returning UInt32, or how to convert this in to a NSData structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple Docs on String formatting https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

`[NSString stringWithFormat:"my unsigned 32-bit int: %d", [self addDataVer]];`

from Apple Docs about NSString class

To convert your entire string to data:

`[myNSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks very much, one last question if you don't know it thats fine, I'm researching it at the moment. But if I wanted to log this data in hex format how could I do that? I have seen one example but its giving me issues.